# NextJS 9: Render sub route in parent route component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a setup where I'm able to render content in layers, based on the current route path.

My setup is currently the following:

1. I have a *layout.tsx* component to wrap all my main routes. This is placed in a shared components folder.
2. I have a folder called *articles*, with an *index.tsx* in it. It uses the *layout.tsx* file to reuse the general feel.
3. I would like to have my path setup to something like */articles/:id*.

Now if the current path is something like */articles/1*, then I would like to be able to render something in my *articles/index.tsx* file based on the **id** given in the path, . Like how you in *react-router* uses a *Route* component. Or you use a *yield* in Ember and what not.

I think I need something like a catch all component that'll serve stuff like either the *index.tsx* or *[id].tsx* file. But do I need to handle that myself, or can NextJS do the heavy lifting for me?